# The HTF bar_index returned by request.security() goes crazy after 28 February?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

This script shows how on a 1M chart `request.security` called for 1M timeframe returns new bar_index on 28 February, then goes to old bar_index for 1 and 2 March and back to the new one on the 3rd March every year. Why?
(please see [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exiqe.png))

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")


htfBi = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", bar_index) 

plotchar(bar_index, "bar_index", "", location = location.bottom)
plotchar(htfBi, "htfBi", "", location = location.bottom)
plot(htfBi)
```

Comment: You can't do request.security of bar_index. What is the requirement?

Comment: The problem is that if you request, e.g., `high` it will behave the same way. On 28 Feb (the last 1D candle within 1M candle) it will return high for the February. But on 1 and 2 March it will return January high and then on 3rd March again February's high.

Comment: As seen here: https://imgur.com/a/u0LIon6
```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")


htfBi = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", bar_index) 
htfHi = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", high) 

plotchar(bar_index, "bar_index", "", location = location.bottom)
plotchar(htfBi, "htfBi", "", location = location.bottom)

plotchar(htfHi, "htfHi", "", location = location.bottom)
plotchar(ta.highest(high,30), "highest(high,30)", "", location = location.bottom) // approx

plot(htfHi)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug, better to report this to Tradingview Support.

Comment: Reported, thank you. Already over 5 bugs reported and admitted ("We’ve identified the issue and assigned a task to our tech team already. "), not counting a number of Pine Editor bugs. And I just started coding in Pine a month ago...

Comment: From Support: "Our technical team is already working on a solution."